# What changed in firefox 3.6 to make <ul>'s render differently?

Tags: html, firefox, internet-explorer-6, google-chrome

**Edit (Solution Discovered)**

Thanks everyone for your help on this. The problem was an error in one of the lines of CSS that was being included (it's a large project with a huge combined CSS file so it was hard to spot). This was the problem line:

```
background:transparent url(sf-pager.gif') repeat-x scroll bottom;
```

Notice the missing apostrophe. IE6, IE7, and Firefox 3.5 seem to just ignore this line and continue with the rest of the combined CSS file no problem. Firefox 3.6 and Google Chrome error out on this line and refuse to include the rest of the combined CSS file. Problem solved!!!

Here's the original unedited question...

I'm developing a webapp for IE6 (unfortunately) but also using firefox and chrome on the side. I've noticed a weird problem where my ul lists are not rendered properly in chrome. They were rendering fine in IE6/IE7 and firefox 3.5, but after upgrading to firefox 3.6 it now looks the same as chrome. Here's what this menu is supposed to look like (IE6/firefox 3.5):

[IE6 http://thebe.jtan.com/~vince/so/ie6.PNG](http://thebe.jtan.com/~vince/so/ie6.PNG)

And here's what it looks like in Chrome and Firefox 3.6:

[Firefox3.6/Chrome http://thebe.jtan.com/~vince/so/firefox.PNG](http://thebe.jtan.com/~vince/so/firefox.PNG)

The code roughly looks like this:

```
<ul id="navMain">
  <li class="navMainLink">Top header</li>
  <li class="navMainLink">Top header 2 with dropdown
    <div class="navpop-wrapper" style="display:none;">
      <div class="navpop">
        <div class="navpop-header">A header in the popup</div>
        <div class="navpop-body">
          <ul>
            <li>An item</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and some jquery onready:

```
$('#navMain li.navMainLink').hover(
    function() { $('div.navpop-wrapper', this).css('display', ''); },
    function() { $('div.navpop-wrapper', this).css('display', 'none'); }
);
$('#navMain .navpop-wrapper').bgiframe();
```

and here's the CSS:

```
#navMain
{
    float: right;
    height: 2.5em;
    padding-bottom: .4em;
    width: 420px;
    list-style: none; 
    margin:0;
}
.navpop-wrapper
{   
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:276px;
    z-index:10000;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}
.navpop
{
    background:white;
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:6px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.navpop-header
{
    height:19px;
    margin:4px;
    clear:both;
}
.navpop-body
{
    clear:both;
}
.navpop-body div
{
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
}
.navpop-body ul 
{
    list-style-type:square;
    margin: 0 6px 3px 0px;
}
.navpop-body ul li
{
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:black;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:0;
    margin-left:24px;
}
#navMain li.navMainLink
{ 
    float: left; 
    border: 1px solid #C8D7E1;
}
```

Any ideas on what changed from firefox 3.5 to 3.6? Clearly 3.6 is now acting the same as chrome.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but isn't it erroneous to place a `<div/>` inside of a `<ul/>` without putting it in a `<li/>`?

Comment: I know nobody (including myself) likes to link their "under construction" work on SO, but a live link would make things much, much easier.

Comment: I'm sorry... it's on a private intranet and I can't link to it. Would if I could. It's too complex to export as well --- there's a lot of C# code going on to generate all of that.

Comment: Also just to add... this is happening as well with a jquery slider. Same problem, different code. So I don't think it's anything specific with this code... I think it's some kind of HTML enforcement change in chrome/FF3.6

Comment: The way to solve these issues (and to report issues to the browser vendors) is to minimize the page as much as possible. Yes, it's not fun, but you should do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Nickolay. It's built using a complex ASP.NET MVC system but I'm going to try pulling some pieces out to hone in the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like several classes, or a complete stylesheet, are not being applied. Can you check using Firebug whether your styles actually apply? Maybe the problem is that a stylesheet is not loading in FF3.6/Chrome for whatever reason.

For everything else, I think you need to show more code, or provide a direct link.

Comment: Accckkk! My mistake. That li was not supposed to end there. My mistake. The post has been updated.

Comment: o.k. I edited my answer. Can you check whether all your stylesheets/classes are applied?

Comment: It looks like maybe the style isn't being applied. I use an HTTPCombiner which combines several stylesheets, although when I look at that file in firebug I don't see those styles present in firefox 3.6. If I click Edit on the stylesheet it's there, but it's not in the pretty spaced out version. Why would this happen?

Comment: Also, I tried validating the CSS for the menu using W3C's CSS Validator and it checks out and says no error found. Yet I'm a little puzzled while it's not showing up in firebug's CSS view (but is showing up in the edit CSS view)

Comment: Is the CSS visible in the CSS file that was referred to by the document? If it is, then it's probably not being applied because some selector is now interpreted differently. But looking at your CSS, I can't see how that would happen, the classes are very straightforward (I would expect trouble with more complex constructs like `*` or `>` or `[attribute=value]`). Dashes `-` are valid for CSS classes o it can't be that, either. Can you clarify on what exactly is the problem, the CSS file or the applying of classes? Is the CSS you quoted complete?

Comment: I believe the applying of classes is the problem. In firebug's CSS view, I don't see those classes listed in firefox 3.6. I do see them listed in firefox 3.5. When I load the "edit" view of the CSS though (seeing the dirty minified version of it), I see those classes in both.

Comment: This turned out to be correct. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction... see top of question for a further explanation of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox 3.6 includes a new version of the Gecko rendering engine.

I ran into at least one issue with a slightly older version of MooTools when I tried the beta of FF 3.6, so I would check your page with and without the Jquery involved, as it's possible it's the javascript changes that are causing issues and not the HTML itself.

Basic layout rendering should not have changed that much, so it's more likely an obscure CSS change (such as interaction between unusual elements) or a javascript handling change.

Comment: I don't think there are supposed to be incompatible changes in 3.6. Please file bugs / raise the issues on the mozilla dev forums!

Answer (score 1):

Did you check to see if there were any CSS parsing warnings in the error console?

Comment: Yes there are CSS errors but they have been there before the firefox upgrade. I'll look to see if there are any present that weren't present in the 3.5 firefox version.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting to note that FF 3.6 is stricter in how it interprets CSS (i.e., it was looking for that extra apostophe)