# Inconsistent height of text input elements between Firefox and WebKit

Tags: css, firefox, webkit

OK, I realize that this is something of an eternal question, but here goes:

I've got a single text input,

```
<input type="text" name="whatever" />
```

and I've specified its `font-family`, `font-size` and `padding`. Yet, even on the same machine (my Mac, let's say), the input has a different height in Firefox (3.6) than it does in Chrome or Safari. Specifically, Firefox adds a little bit more padding below the text.

And no, specifying `height` in pixels doesn't achieve consistency either.

Is there any way to achieve text input height consistency across Gecko- and WebKit-based browsers (let alone IE and Opera) without resorting to JavaScript? And if I must use JavaScript, has someone already devised a jQuery plugin or something to easily do this?

**Update:** Here's what not to do. The [jqTransform](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) plugin lets you skin form elements and promises that they'll look the same across browsers. Here's how the demo input looks in Chrome 5 on my Mac:

[image: jqTransform Chrome input]

and here's how the same input looks in Firefox 3.6.4:

[image: jqTransform Firefox input]

I haven't altered these screenshots in any way, just cropped them. Now, my first reaction is, "Ugh, I don't want to support Firefox." But there are currently more Firefox users than Safari and Chrome users combined, so that's not an option.

Someone, please help! I just want my forms to look the same across *modern, standards-compliant* browsers! And by "look the same," I'm not talking about the `outline` on selection or anything like that; I'm just talking about having the same width, height, and text placement!

Comment: I had a similar problem with a larger input and a larger button next to it - could not reconcile alignment issues between Firefox, IE and Safari - the best I could do is one out of three :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's a "solution" that I worked out if you really want `<input type="text">` elements to look exactly the same in the current versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox. Note that I haven't tested this in Opera or IE, or on operating systems other than Mac OS; I'm sure additional hacks would be needed.

I simply define a `<div>` to provide the background for the input, and give the input itself the properties `background: none`, `border: 0`, etc. In other words, the input is just floating text. Then I position the input over the background by using relative positioning (specifically, setting the input's `top`). That leaves me free to adjust it for the different browsers. Specifically, I found that the input text was 1px higher in Webkit-based browsers than in Firefox, so I added the line

```
if ($.browser.webkit) { $input.css('marginTop', 1); }
```

Now the input finally looks exactly the same between Webkit and Firefox. It's a hack, yes, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Does this other question help you : [Firefox 3.6 and CSS difference from previous versions of Firefox 3.5 and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133740/firefox-3-6-and-css-difference-from-previous-versions-of-firefox-3-5-and-back) ?

Thus, do you see any difference between fx 3.6 and Fx3.5- ?

Comment: I don't have Firefox 3.5 handy, but I feel pretty sure that I saw this kind of inconsistency before 3.6 came out...

Answer (score 0):

if ($.browser.webkit) { $(".jqTransformInputInner div input").css("padding-top","10px");}